# How to prove this equality: $\int_0^x(x-t)e^{\cos t}dt=\int_0^x\bigg(\int_0^te^{\cos s}ds\bigg)dt$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to show this equality is true:

$$\int_0^x(x-t)e^{\cos t}dt=\int_0^x\bigg(\int_0^te^{\cos s}ds\bigg)dt$$

I used the fundamental theorem of calculus without success. I need a hint how to solve this question.

Comment: Hint: Look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) on differentiation under the integral sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x(x-t)e^{\cos t}\,dt=
x\int_0^xe^{\cos t}\,dt-\int_0^xte^{\cos t}\,dt
$$
Then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
F'(x)=\int_0^xe^{\cos t}\,dt+xe^{\cos x}-xe^{\cos x}=
\int_0^xe^{\cos t}\,dt
$$
Compute the derivative of the right-hand side and then evaluate both at $0$.

Comment: The derivative $F'(x)$ of the LHS is the same as the derivative of the RHS. I didn't understand what I do with this information. The LHS differs from the RHS by a constant, right? thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user42912 Yes, the two sides are everywhere defined and have the same derivative; since at $0$ they have the same value…

Answer (score 3):

Let's switch the order of integration for the double integral on the right side.

The current bounds are $0 \le t \le x$ and $0 \le s \le t$. This can be combined as $0 \le s \le t \le x$. So the bounds when integrating with respect to $t$ first are $0 \le s \le x$ and $s \le t \le x$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle\int_0^x\left(\int_0^te^{\cos s}\,ds\right)\,dt$ $= \displaystyle\int_0^x\left(\int_s^xe^{\cos s}\,dt\right)\,ds$ $= \displaystyle\int_0^x(x-s)e^{\cos s}\,ds$.

Now replace $s$ in the last integral with $t$.

Comment: Why can we switch the order of the differentials $ds, dt$? thank you!

Comment: See the last theorem on [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)).

Comment: Isn't the correct bound $0\le s\le x$?

Comment: ^correct bound for which integral? For the first integral, for each fixed $t$, $s$ varies from $0$ to $t$. For the second integral, $s$ does vary from $0$ to $x$, which is what I have.

Comment: yes, yes you're right. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts:
$$ \int_0^x (x-t) e^{\cos{t}} \, dt = \left[ (x-t)\int_0^t e^{\cos{s}} \, ds \right]_{t=0}^x - \int_0^x (-1) \int_0^t e^{\cos{s}} \, ds \, dt. $$
The first term vanishes at the endpoints, the second is what you want.

Comment: Could you please, explain a little bit more how do you integrate this by parts? what are $u$ and $dv$? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to differentiate $(x-t)e^{cos t}$ with respect to $t$. :-)